# Import a data base file.json into robo3T (robomongo)

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, nosql

I have a file named services.json containing a data base that I exported from a windows mongodb, and I want to import that file into robomongo (connected to mongodb installed by npm) on Ubuntu.

I'm a beginner and I don't know how to proceed, which terminal use (robomongo or Ubuntu)?

Comment: Robomongo — is a shell-centric crossplatform MongoDB management tool. Provides nice GUI

Answer (score 16):

to import data for a collection in Robomongo:

1. Right click on collection.
2. Select 'insert Document'.
   [image]
3. Paste your json data
4. Click validate.
5. Click save.

Comment: The only problem with this method is how unresponsible the UI becomes when parsing large JSON files.

Comment: This method create a single document with 500 child parameters, instead create 500 documents...

Comment: Just as @BartolomeuS.Gusella said, this inserts only 1 document in the database. In order to add multiple documents, this doesn't work. Probably [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441228/insert-json-file-into-mongodb?answertab=votes#tab-top) would do it

Comment: This method does not work for very big collections

Answer (score 10):

Ok, I found the answer. In shell Mac OS X or Unix type:

```
$ mongoimport -d your Database Name -c your Collection Name --file /path/to/my/fileThatIwantToImport.json
```

Comment: Do you know how to import s.th. with Robomongo/ Mac Shell if the database is outside of your local environment. E.g. on a server without accessing the server shell?

Comment: @AndiGiga I provided an answer showing how to import to a remotedb

Comment: Tried it on windows and it works fine
The mongoimport.exe is present in the bin folder where MongoDb is installed. The above answer worked just fine for me.. Just imported a 5 GB Json file. Took some time though

Answer (score 7):

For anyone wishing to use mongoimport with a remote db (@andi-giga), here's what I did to make it work:

```
mongoimport -h  xxx.mlab.com --port 2700  -d db_name -c collection_name -u user_name -p password  --type json --file  /Path/to/file.json
```

Arguments should be self-explanatory.

`-h hostname`

More information at [this link](https://supundharmarathne.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/importing-json-file-into-your-remote-mongodb-database-with-mongohq/)

Answer (score 5):

I don't have enough points to comment on Varun's answer, but if you use *export jsonArray* and then import using Robo3T (Robomongo), make sure to **remove the commas in between the objects, as well as remove the square brackets.**

It's not really a JSON format that ROBO 3T accepts, but rather bunch of JSON objects separated by newlines.

(if you use *export Standard*, then it's already formatted for document insert)

Comment: Note that while you can't comment on answers just yet, you can suggest an edit to a post if you have additional information to add. You can do this by clicking the "edit" link just below the posts' text.

Answer (score 3):

if this is not a bson, and only json, you can use `mongoimport --jsonArray` . refference [Insert json file into mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441228/insert-json-file-into-mongodb)

Answer (score 3):

*RoboMongo* is just the UI for your **mongod** which is the primary *daemon process* for the MongoDB system.

The only option to import from RoboMongo is

```
Right Click on Collection -> Insert Document
```

Apart from this you can import using the *mongoimport* command from terminal.

1. Open terminal and type mongo
2. Now in mongo interactive shell
3. Use the following command to import the json file as collection

> mongoimport -d database_name -c collection_name --file < path to the
>   json file

Answer (score 2):

Tested :

```
mongoimport --jsonArray -d <DataBase Name> -c <Collection Name> --file /path/to/my/fileThatIwantToImport.json
```

It works very well!

Comment: I would like to point out that I visted the man page to figure out csv files, and this can be done with the --type csv flag in place of --jsonArray

Answer (score 0):

Insert Document will insert all the JSON file data under a single document.
Apparently the tool does not support JSON import.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to import the database into MongoDB. one is with robomongo/Robo 3T and one is with a shell command. I always choose the second method due to fewer and easy steps.

**FIRST METHOD**

Install MongoDB on your machine. Also, check it was installed properly or not by using mongod command on your terminal. So, for importing a new DB on your MongoDB write this command on your terminal

```
mongostore -host <HostIp | 127.0.0.1> -port <mongoPort | 27017> -db <DBname> <Directory-path>
```

So, for example you’re running MongoDB on local machine with default port i.e 27017 and your DB files are store at /usr/library/userDatabase then write this command and check DB is imported in your MongoDB

```
mongostore -host 127.0.0.1 -port 27017 -db userDatabase /usr/library/userDatabase
```

For more details check this article.
[Import MongoDB using shell and robomongo/Robo 3T](https://medium.com/@Harry_1408/import-a-database-into-mongodb-robomongo-5c30febaf227)