# Set field value with big amount of text in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Using the terminal, I need to set a field in the document with a text, like an article for example, but it seems to be too long, this text certainly is lower than 16MB.

db.test.insertOne({
_id: 10, 
text: "/article content/", 
qty: 5 
})

Only set it as a normal field, returns a Syntax Error.

SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @(shell):1:9

What would be the best way to insert this document, with this field, in the collection?

Comment: Most likely if you can load the content into a variable and use that you'll be golden. 
Check out this answer (inserting from a file): https://stackoverflow.com/a/39620301/3788456.