# Initialize data on the database (Spring & Mongo)

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I'm using mongock to generate the initial data on the database and so far it's working fine for `Country` but still a long way to go

```js
@ChangeUnit(id="country-initializer", order = "1")
public class CountryInitializerCU {

    @BeforeExecution
    public void beforeExecution(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        mongoTemplate.createCollection(COUNTRY_COLLECTION_NAME);
    }

    @RollbackBeforeExecution
    public void rollbackBeforeExecution() {
        // do nothing
    }

    @Execution
    public void execution(CountryRepository countryRepository) {
        List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<>();

        countries.add(new Country("AM", "ARM", "Armenia"));
        countries.add(new Country("AL", "ALB", "Albania"));
        countries.add(new Country("AO", "AGO", "Angola"));
        countries.add(new Country("BS", "BHS", "Bahamas"));
        countries.add(new Country("BY", "BLR", "Bahamas"));
        // TODO

        countryRepository.saveAll(countries);

    }

    @RollbackExecution
    public void rollbackExecution(MongoTemplate mongoTemplate) {
        mongoTemplate.dropCollection(COUNTRY_COLLECTION_NAME);
    }
}
```

The problem that I see now is that I need to to the same for `Places`. The problem is that `Places` have `140.000 records`. Imagine filling that by hand. I have those places in a 200MB json file that I could use instead of filling manually.

What is the best approach?

Comment: did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19441228/insert-json-file-into-mongodb

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you may do here is:

1. Place the JSON file as a resource in your project.
2. Add some logic in your migration to [read](https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-a-file-from-resources-folder/) resource file and deseriliza using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson), [gson](https://github.com/google/gson) or any JSON library of your preference.
3. Transform these records into `Country` instances and save them into the database as you are doing right now.